# Redis connection sometimes times out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redis

> Timeout performing SCAN (5000ms), inst: 0, qu: 1, qs: 0, aw: False,
> bw: SpinningDown, rs: NotStarted, ws: Initializing, in: 0, last-in: 0,
> cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 3, serverEndpoint:
> redis-cache:6379, conn-sec: n/a, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10
> available, clientName: 4ad737d5e712(SE.Redis-v2.7.10.12442), IOCP:
> (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=50,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=11,Free=32756,Min=50,Max=32767), POOL:
> (Threads=19,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=1460,Timers=46), v:
> 2.7.10.12442

Previously, the busy value in the worker was greater than the min value. I increased the number of `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` to 50 to see if that would solve the problem but the same problem persists. I need your help on how to solve this problem.